# Display email draft and send in Outlook on Button Click in Angular/NodeJs

Tags: node.js, angular, outlook, nodemailer, node-webkit

I have a requirement wherein on click of button on a dialog, I want an email draft that will popup in Outlook so that any message can be customized before sharing the same.
This is to be integrated in Angular/Nodejs Application.

I assume below possibilities on same.
1.Using Angular to display emailsIds to which mail would be sent
2.On click of "send Email" button,there would be a nodeJs service call that would open Outlook with prepopulated emailIds selected from first screen and using node-outlook library setup up outlook call.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-outlook

Please suggest if any better approach possible for same and also if anyone has worked on such requirement a working demo code would be very helpful to build this on.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use window.open and mailTo protocol to open the email draft at client end.
window.open('mailto:abc@gmail.com;xyz@gmail.com?cc=pqr@gmail.com&subject=Subject&body=Hello World', '_self');

All Details required to be displayed on the mail could be fetched through node service calls.